# How can I install gnome-photos in 13.10?

Tags: apt

Using 13.10 Unity, how can I install gnome-photos from gnome 3.10?

Here's a sample package from fedora: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=15095

I added this repo
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/gnome_3?dist=saucy
but still it cannot be found:

`apt-get install gnome-photos
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gnome-photos`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it's not being found, yet the repository is there, then the software lists haven't been updated. Because that package name *is* in the repository. Run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and try again.

Comment: Thanks. The package seems to be only for raring: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas?exact_match=1&q=gnome-photos